# Ajax calling scope $. Asynchronous request

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm using some library called "jquery-comments". It initializes itself this way:

```
var commentsArray = [bla bla bla];
jQuery(function($){
    $('#comments-container').comments({
        getComments: function(success, error) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                success(commentsArray);
            }, 500);
        }
    });
});
```

It all working fine but now I wanna to load "commentsArray" asynchronously from URL. I tried doing this:

```
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200) {
        var commentsArray = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText);
        jQuery(function($){
            $('#comments-container').comments({
                getComments: function(success, error) {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        success(commentsArray);
                    }, 500);
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
xmlHttp.open("GET", "/getComments", true);
xmlHttp.send(null);
```

It gives me error:

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).comments is not a function.
```

I understand it's because I called it from scope of nested function but I cannot find a solution myself. How can I prevent this error and let it load asynchronously?

Comment: have you tryed to add bind(this) at the end of Jquery(...).bind(this) ?

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi Tried just now, didn't work.

Comment: Sounds like you're including a second copy of jquery. Your solution just scopes the code within it to a particular copy that happens to have the plugin.

Comment: @Kevin B The thing is that $('#....') works in plain html but does not in spring-boot or wordpress. So I googled a solution to this as jQuery(function($){ . And scopes, yes that was my problem, cause it didn't worked in sub func context, so I have to save object to use it later in callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution myself.
In case it would be useful for someone:

```
var nastyObject = null;
jQuery(function($){
    nastyObject = $('#comments-container');

    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200) {
            var commentsArray = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText);
            nastyObject.comments({
                getComments: function(success, error) {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        success(commentsArray);
                    }, 500);
                }
            });
        }
    }
    xmlHttp.open("GET", "/getComments", true);
    xmlHttp.send(null);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that you have loaded `.comments` library first.

Since you are using jQuery, use it for Ajax too:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/getComments',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (commentsArray) {
        $('#comments-container').comments({
            getComments: function(success, error) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    success(commentsArray);
                }, 500);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: In plain html it works but in spring boot or woldpress, if I use $('#comments-container') directly instead of jQuery(function($){$('#comments-container') I getting same error.

Comment: Aslo, it does getting response from my server, I see it in log but   "success: function (res) {"     do not getting fired.